# Do Devas have sukshma sharira?

Tags: gods, body

Do Devas have sukshma sharira? If they have then, does that mean that sukshma sharira also have mind, chitta, buddhi, akhamkara? Please explain.

Comment: Yes till brahma they have both Sushma and pancha boothika(in their lokas) only thing is they are able operate them effectively.. because even normal human sometimes in sleep feel out of body he can his own body sleeping and then tries moves his own hand wont be able too after much effort body moves, in effect human wont be knowing how to operate the Sushma sarira when alive.. Devas know.. the pancha boothika sarira in their lokas will get dispersed just like human body and move to higher lokas. Brahma attains moksha by reqlinquising his panchaboothika, Sushma and ling bodies.

Comment: @Prasannaragothaman can u send me some audio discourses or books links related to this topic

Comment: you have bannaje govidacharya conversation.. Madhvacharya in tantrasarasangrha on how to do deva upsane i.e. meditate

Comment: @PrasannaR any particular scriptures talking of this aspect?

Comment: First you need to go to creation to understand the bodies are formed.. wiht  24 tattvas and ttatv abhimani devatas will give the link ..does this apply to all living being other god himself yes with out prakruthi sambhanda no creation can happen.. i.e. except Lakshmi she avayktha along with sriman Narayana all are created out of prakruthi and part of creation.. so they pancha bhootic sarirana as we do but in their lokha but if you they want to travel to downward plan to earthe they do with suskhma and they can also be present in every body..

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/34866/are-there-verses-from-scriptures-which-list-24-tattvas-according-to-sankhya-dars @Archit

Comment: @Prasanna R Oh oh very nice!!!! I meant reference to what devtas can do- like you explained above. Had come across a very indirect reference in the Garuda Purana where Bhagwan Vishnu is described having all 25 tattvas- panchamahabhoot etc in Vaikunthalok

Comment: Sorry to clarify Sriman Narayana and Lakshmi Devi have aprakrutha sarira no sambanda of content of prakruthi all others have panchabhoota sarira @Archit reference B.G. 15 .16 akshara are narayana and lakshmi rest all shra

Comment: @PrasannaR sorry not a reference for Lakshmi Narayana being avyakta, but for devatas having Pancha mahabhuta bodies and travelling to earth using only Sukshma bodies

Comment: Shra its only panchabootika i believe @Archit and also Agni is seen in sthula form also, Vayu can be felt, Akasha can be seen as space above.. We can Varun as liquid water.. That means these devatas also present themselves in sthula form in panchabhootika sarira in earth.. The actual experience is more than proof of any scripture..

Comment: @Prasanna R, impressive but seeing their bhuta sharira here means they have only one of the pancha mahabhuta here. Eg Agni is only fire here, Varuna only water, whereas they’ve traditionally been represented with a form and a vahana. But very impressed by the observation

Comment: see again you counting only one primary bhoota which can be seen.. suppose im saying earth has fire, water air and space.. all this can be present in atomic level .. you have to go to atomic level and there is no way that you can deny every element have five within only one primary is shown..how agni is present arni kattai.. or match even its fired.. match box have agni but its not shown.. similarly agni requires air within that is oxygen here one take brindaranya upanishad where it says only vayu tattva supports everything in  the universe.@Archit

Comment: sun, moon, atomic level its makes the universe to function